# How to purge unmanaged dsc_xfirewall resources with puppet on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet, dsc

We're trying to implement windows host firewalls with dsc_xfirewall and doing a normal puppet resource purge:

```
resources { 'dsc_xfirewall': 
purge => true, 
}
```

However, this appears not to be supported in the dsc module (https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-2270). What's the best way to remove any firewall rules not specified by a dsc_xfirewall resource?

Comment: you will murder the vm if you do so, there are hundreds of system rules

Comment: There are, but most are disabled in our current setup. Moreover, any that we do need we'd like to explicitly state in a puppet manifest, rather than just holdover from Windows' default setup.